# losing entries when iterating hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, glassfish, javabeans

I'm using a hashmap in an application scoped javabean to store user sessions. I use the following code to push to these sessions using a socketconnection:

```
public void sendToAllFollowers(User user, JsonObject message) throws IOException
{
    List<User> followingUsers = user.getFollowers();


    System.out.println(hashmap.size() + " active sessions before.");

    for(User u : followingUsers)
    {
        System.out.println(u.getUserName() + " found in followers list");

        Iterator it = hashmap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HashMap.Entry pair = (HashMap.Entry)it.next();
            User tempUser = (User) pair.getKey();
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

            if(tempUser.getUserName().equals(u.getUserName()))
            {
                System.out.println(u.getUserName() + " found in hashmap: has active session");
                Session sendtosession = (Session) pair.getValue();
                sendtosession.getBasicRemote().sendText(message.toString());                      
            }
        }
    }
System.out.println(hashmap.size() + " active sessions after.");
}
```

As you can see, I write the size of the hashmap to the server log twice. Once before iterating and once after. After iterating the size is always zero...

Any idea as to what might cause this? As I said, it's in an application scoped bean, and deployed in a web app using glassfish 4.1.0

Also, I sometimes get this error when starting the app:

```
Severe:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Thread's context class loader is null
at org.glassfish.weld.ACLSingletonProvider$ACLSingleton.getClassLoader(ACLSingletonProvider.java:147)
at org.glassfish.weld.ACLSingletonProvider$ACLSingleton.get(ACLSingletonProvider.java:108)
at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:65)
```

Could that have something to do with it?

Current output in console:

```
Info:   1 active sessions before.
Info:   jan found in followers list
Info:   jan found in hashmap: has active session
Info:   merel found in followers list
Info:   0 active sessions after.
```

Comment: what is the current output?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Theres no error or anything, the entries are just gone

Comment: what do you have in you console if you prefer

Comment: BTW using a non thread safe object like an HashMap for application scoped bean doesn't sound to be a good idea to me

Comment: Why are you calling `it.remove()`?

Comment: Info:   1 active sessions before.
    Info:   jan found in followers list
    Info:   merel found in followers list
    Info:   0 active sessions after.

Comment: You're calling `it.remove` for each element and never put data again in your hashmap, what are you expecting from this action?

Comment: @nowherebound123 put the output in your question please not as comment otherwise it is hard to follow

Comment: the itterator part i copied from a different stack question, it's removed from the itterator but not from the hashmap right, so shouldnt be a problem i thought?

Comment: @nowherebound123 wrong, it removes it from the map too, this is your bug

Comment: Straight from java doc "Iterator.remove() Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation)."

Comment: @nowherebound123 This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Also, it seems that you may be doing some unnecessary casting our should be utilizing Java generics on your HashMap and Iterator like you are for your list of users.